# Adding thread product to array

Tags: java, arraylist, threadpool

I have to add the objects of a threadpool to an `ArrayList`, in order to count the total amount of objects my threadpool has created. For that I have created an `ArrayList`, and after I execute my threadpool I add the object to the `ArrayList`. My problem is that the new threadpools overwrite the existing object in my `Arraylist` and therefore the `Arraylist` will always stay the same size, no matter how many times the code is run.

My `ArrayList`:

```
 protected ArrayList<Runnable> ComponentBuild = new ArrayList<>();
```

Where the threads are started:

```
public void tireComponent() {
    Menu menu = new Menu();
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    //  ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        Runnable tire = new Tire("" + i);
        executor.execute(tire);
        ComponentBuild.add(tire);
        System.out.println(ComponentBuild);
        if (ComponentBuild.size() == MAX_CAPACITY) {
            sleep();
        }
    }
```

Tire class:

```
public class Tire implements Runnable, Component {

    private String number;

    public Tire(String Number) {
        this.number = Number;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Tire number " + number + " has now begun creation");

        processCommand();

        System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has now created number " + number + " tire");
    }

    private void processCommand() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.number;
    }
}
```

Outcome in terminal:

```
You have the following options: 
1) Create normal trie
2) Create winter tire
3) Create premium tire
1
[1]
Tire number 1 has now begun creation
[1, 2]
Tire number 2 has now begun creation
[1, 2, 3]

You have the following options: 
1) Create normal trie
2) Create winter tire
3) Create premium tire
Tire number 3 has now begun creation
Thread pool-1-thread-2 has now created number 2 tire
Thread pool-1-thread-1 has now created number 1 tire
Thread pool-1-thread-3 has now created number 3 tire
1
[1]
Tire number 1 has now begun creation
[1, 2]
Tire number 2 has now begun creation
[1, 2, 3]
You have the following options: 
1) Create normal trie
2) Create winter tire
3) Create premium tire
Tire number 3 has now begun creation
Thread pool-2-thread-1 has now created number 1 tire
Thread pool-2-thread-2 has now created number 2 tire
Thread pool-2-thread-3 has now created number 3 tire
```

I would like it so the output would be like this

```
Tire number 2 has now begun creation
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

But the actual output is the second threadpool overwriting the existing objects in my array, so no matter how many times I run the code, the `ArrayList` will always be:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Edit: As requested, my Component interface:

```
package Model;

public interface Component {

 void run();
 String toString();
}
```

Comment: Quick question: why are you implementing `Component`? Is it `java.awt.Component`, which is a class?

Comment: Component is the name of my interface I made myself. I can show you the interface, if it would help you understand it.

Comment: Yes, that would help.

Answer (score 0):

You are running your loop only three times 'for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)' so it will have only three. If you want more you need to increase the loop size.