# Trying to learn how to use Theadpool generate mesh data

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, threadpool

I want to generate a mesh tile data on one thread and store it in some kind of array or list that is sorted in a predictable way. Need to access them at later point for placement. 
In the script below I want to execute the "void CreatingTile" on the threadpool and then assign it to a certain index in a list or array.

But if I can see a simple example that adds a values on a threadpool into a thread safe array or list, then I could possibly solve it by myself. I am new to C# and I want to learn how to utilize threading in general. Have read through the [threadpool docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_ThreadPool_QueueUserWorkItem_System_Threading_WaitCallback_System_Object_) but Fibonacci number is something that I am not familiar with, so it's a bit hard for me to follow.

edit: So my question is how do i implement threading and store the resulting mesh data in a array or list?

The Current script (working code)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Threading;


public class TerrainGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{



    public int xVertices = 20;
    public int zVertices = 20;




    void Start()
    {

        TileData tileData = new TileData(xVertices, zVertices);

        Vector3 positionV3 = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

        GameObject terrain;
        terrain = new GameObject("Empty");


        MeshRenderer meshRenderer = terrain.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        meshRenderer.sharedMaterial = new Material(Shader.Find("Standard"));
        MeshFilter meshFilter = terrain.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();

        CreatingTile(tileData);

        terrain.transform.position = positionV3;


        meshFilter.mesh = tileData.CreateMesh();

    }


    void CreatingTile(TileData tileData)
    {


        for (int i = 0, z = 0; z <= zVertices; z++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= xVertices; x++)
            {
                float y = Mathf.PerlinNoise(x * .3f, z * .3f) * 2f;
                tileData.vertices[i] = new Vector3(x, y, z);
                i++;

            }

        }


        int vert = 0;
        int tris = 0;
        for (int z = 0; z < zVertices; z++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < xVertices; x++)
            {


                tileData.triangles[tris + 0] = vert + 0;
                tileData.triangles[tris + 1] = vert + xVertices + 1;
                tileData.triangles[tris + 2] = vert + 1;
                tileData.triangles[tris + 3] = vert + 1;
                tileData.triangles[tris + 4] = vert + xVertices + 1;
                tileData.triangles[tris + 5] = vert + xVertices + 2;

                vert++;
                tris = tris + 6;


            }
            vert++;
        }


        for (int i = 0, z = 0; z <= zVertices; z++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= xVertices; x++)
            {
                tileData.uvs[i] = new Vector2((float)x / xVertices, (float)z / zVertices);
                i++;
            }
        }

    }

    public class TileData
    {

        public Vector3[] vertices;
        public int[] triangles;
        public Vector2[] uvs;

        public TileData(int xVertices, int zVertices)
        {
            vertices = new Vector3[(xVertices + 1) * (zVertices + 1)];
            uvs = new Vector2[vertices.Length];
            triangles = new int[xVertices * zVertices * 6];

        }

        public Mesh CreateMesh()
        {
            Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
            mesh.vertices = vertices;
            mesh.triangles = triangles;
            mesh.uv = uvs;
            mesh.RecalculateNormals();
            return mesh;
        }


    }


}
```

Would be thankful for any help on this matter.

Comment: What help? You haven't asked us a question. Can you please clarify what you're asking us?

Comment: Also, the Fibonacci sequence is just `f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n - 2) where f(1) = 1 and f(0) = 0`. It sounds like the threading code is more of an issue?

Comment: @Enigmativity 
might not been have formulated my question correctly. But i want to run the metod "void CreatingTile" via threadpool and then store the result it in a array or list. 

I think i found a similar question but its in Java, its a bit harder to understand [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58186424/adding-thread-product-to-array)

And its more a threading issue, i am not too familiar with the metods relating to threading syntax's. But i understand the concept of threading.

Comment: Have you tried `Parallel.For`?

Comment: Haven't looked at it, was thinking that I would learn threadpool for a more general approach, so I have only done tests with threads and threadpool
But I will check it out when I get home.

Comment: @Enigmativity Looked at `Parallel.For` a bit but while i am still learning, i would like to limit the amount of different versions of threading to threadpool or tasks. My current understanding of thread makes it easier to understand.

Comment: I have done some test to try using the `Task` metod and i am trying to test if i can get ConcurrentQueue container to store a Array with two numbers.That way i can what tile was executed, and in that way i can know how each tile are related.
But when i run the script all the tasks outputs the same respons.Not really sure what i am doing wrong

Comment: `tasknumber` just shows the value 10

`
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            
            tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => Adding(2000, i));

        }
        Debug.Log("Starting tasks");


    void Adding(int length, int tasknumber)
    {

        int[] ArrayTest = new int[2] {tasknumber, 10};
        TestCQ.Enqueue(ArrayTest);
        Thread.Sleep(length)
        Debug.Log("Task " + tasknumber);

    }
`

Comment: Using `Thread`, instead of `Task` or any of the other higher-level thread abstractions, is just a way of experiencing pain.

Comment: Try `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { var x = i; tasks[x] = Task.Run(()...`.

Comment: Decided to go with ´Task´ after reading a about the differences between ´Thread´ and ´Task´. But i am testing some things at the moment and i think i might be able to solve it, just need a bit more of time.

Comment: Tried adding the ´var x = i´ and it worked, now only need to correct the vertex, and make them align at the edge.

Comment: I have solved the problem now, but i want to make it more scalable so it doesn't freeze when i create more tiles, get a 3601 ms spike when it create physics. Will post my solution when i get home, so people see a basic version

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly naive solution which i was able to was able to create with some reading and some help. But its working and using multiple threads.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


public class TerrainGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{


    //the max tileMeshSize is close to 250
    public int tileMeshSize = 250;
    public int tileCountX = 10;
    public int tileCountY = 10;
    public int tileSizeScaleModifier = 1;
    public int perlinNoiseScale = 1;
    public int perlinNoiseheigh = 1;
    //Add Biomes 
    //Terrain characteristics for diffrent areas examples hills ,canyon, plains, sanddunes.
    ConcurrentQueue<TileData> tileCQ = new ConcurrentQueue<TileData>();


    void Start()
    {
        

        Task[] tasks = new Task[tileCountX * tileCountY];
        TileData[] tileArrayData = new TileData[tileCountX * tileCountY];
        GameObject[] terrainTiles = new GameObject[tileCountX * tileCountY];

        for (int i = 0,y = 0; y < tileCountY; y++)
        { 
            for (int x = 0; x < tileCountX; x++)
            {
                // Tile mesh size, int index, int X start position, int Z start position 
                tileArrayData[i] = new TileData(tileMeshSize, i, (tileMeshSize * x), (tileMeshSize * y));
                i++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < (tileCountX * tileCountY); i++)
        {
            var x = i;
            tasks[x] = Task.Run(() => CreatingTile(tileArrayData[x]));
        }

    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (tileCQ.Count == (tileCountX * tileCountY))
        {
            CreatingMeshFromTileData();
            enabled = false;
        }
     
    }


    //Creates multiple meshes
    void CreatingMeshFromTileData()
    {
        TileData[] sortingArray = new TileData[tileCountX * tileCountY];
        TileData[] tileArrayDataReady = new TileData[tileCountX * tileCountY];
        GameObject[] terrainCollection = new GameObject[tileCountX * tileCountY];
        MeshRenderer[] meshRenderers = new MeshRenderer[tileCountX * tileCountY];
        MeshFilter[] meshFilters = new MeshFilter[tileCountX * tileCountY];
        Vector3[] tilePos = new Vector3[tileCountX * tileCountY];
        for (int i = 0; i < (tileCountX * tileCountY); i++)
        {
            tileCQ.TryDequeue(out tileArrayDataReady[i]);

        }

        Array.Sort(tileArrayDataReady,
        delegate (TileData x, TileData y) { return x.tileIndex.CompareTo(y.tileIndex); });


        for (int y = 0, i = 0; y < tileCountY; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < tileCountX; x++)
            {

                tilePos[i] = new Vector3((x * tileMeshSize * tileSizeScaleModifier), 0, (y * tileMeshSize * tileSizeScaleModifier));
                terrainCollection[i] = new GameObject("Empty");
                meshRenderers[i] = terrainCollection[i].AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
                meshFilters[i] = terrainCollection[i].AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
                terrainCollection[i].transform.position = tilePos[i];

                meshFilters[i].mesh = tileArrayDataReady[i].CreateMesh();
                meshRenderers[i].sharedMaterial = new Material(Shader.Find("Standard"));
                i++;
            }
        }        

    }
    //Creating mesh on thread
    void CreatingTile(TileData tileData)
    {
        

        for (int i = 0, z = 0; z <= tileMeshSize; z++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= tileMeshSize; x++)
            {
                float y = Mathf.PerlinNoise((x + tileData.xStartPos) * .3f, (z + tileData.zStartPos) * .3f) * perlinNoiseScale;
                tileData.vertices[i] = new Vector3((x* tileSizeScaleModifier), y, (z* tileSizeScaleModifier));
                i++;
            }
        }


        int vert = 0;
        int tris = 0;
        for (int z = 0; z < tileMeshSize; z++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < tileMeshSize; x++)
            {


                tileData.triangles[tris + 0] = vert + 0;
                tileData.triangles[tris + 1] = vert + tileMeshSize + 1;
                tileData.triangles[tris + 2] = vert + 1;
                tileData.triangles[tris + 3] = vert + 1;
                tileData.triangles[tris + 4] = vert + tileMeshSize + 1;
                tileData.triangles[tris + 5] = vert + tileMeshSize + 2;

                vert++;
                tris = tris + 6;

            }
            vert++;
        }


        for (int i = 0, z = 0; z <= tileMeshSize; z++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= tileMeshSize; x++)
            {
                tileData.uvs[i] = new Vector2((float)x / tileMeshSize, (float)z / tileMeshSize);
                i++;
            }
        }
        tileCQ.Enqueue(tileData);
    }

    public class TileData
    {
        public int tileIndex;
        public Vector3[] vertices;
        public int[] triangles;
        public Vector2[] uvs;

        public int xStartPos;
        public int zStartPos;

        public int xEndPos;
        public int zEndPos;

        public TileData(int tileMeshSize, int index, int xSPos, int zSPos)
        {

            xStartPos = xSPos;
            zStartPos = zSPos;

            xEndPos = xSPos + tileMeshSize;
            zEndPos = zSPos + tileMeshSize;


            tileIndex = index;
            vertices = new Vector3[(tileMeshSize + 1) * (tileMeshSize + 1)];
            uvs = new Vector2[vertices.Length];
            triangles = new int[tileMeshSize * tileMeshSize * 6];

        }

        public Mesh CreateMesh()
        {
            Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
            mesh.vertices = vertices;
            mesh.triangles = triangles;
            mesh.uv = uvs;
            mesh.RecalculateNormals();
            return mesh;
        }


    }

}
```